How to disable log4j programmatic reconfiguration from a 3rd party jar
My project recently migrated from log4j to log4j2 using the bridge approach. Everything works well until we trigger a flow that uses a 3rd party jar which is programmatically reconfiguring log4j. This reconfiguration is done using org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator (log4j-1.2-api-2.17.2). Due to this reconfiguration, my Log4j2 property configuration is getting hijacked closing all the appenders. I have the log4j2.properties on my class path and a System Property is also set to refer log4j2.configurationFile. I enabled the debug and it is printing the the reconfig logs. Please advise how can this programmatic reconfig. can be disabled.
Application is a java based webapp deployed on Websphere.
Here is the reconfiguration log.
**
SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Lookup' found 15 plugins
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger PluginManager 'Log4j Builder' found 19 plugins
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache.axis=[null]
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Parsing for [org.apache.axis] with value=[OFF].
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Level token is [OFF].
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Logger org.apache.axis level set to FATAL
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Finished configuring.
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Parsing for [org.apache.axis] with value=[OFF].
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Level token is [OFF].
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Logger org.apache.axis level set to FATAL
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Finished configuring.
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Configuration org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration@fbb7db8e initialized
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Starting configuration org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration@fbb7db8e
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration@fbb7db8e OK.
 SystemErr     R TRACE StatusLogger Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@983595e...
 SystemErr     R TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration notified 3 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
 SystemErr     R TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration stopping 2 LoggerConfigs.
 SystemErr     R TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
 SystemErr     R TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
 SystemErr     R TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Appender AppFileAppender stopped with status true
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Appender PerfFileAppender stopped with status true
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Appender consoleAppender stopped with status true
 SystemErr     R TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration stopped 3 remaining Appenders.
 SystemErr     R TRACE StatusLogger PropertiesConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 3 LoggerConfigs.
 SystemErr     R DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped

**
Tried multiple options 1. with different properties 2. programmatic configuration 3.setting monitorInterval=0 but nothing works as the log4j2 Property Configuration it self is getting stopped. Only way it works as expected is if we remove PropertiesConfiguration class from bridge jar.

The proper solution would be to report the bug to the developers of the third-party library.
If the purpose of the library is not the configuration of the logging backend, it should not call PropertyConfigurator.
As a workaround you can choose one of these options:

wait for issue #2778 to be solved, which should restore the NO-OP behavior of PropertyConfigurator (this was the behavior in 2.17.1 and earlier releases of log4j-1.2-api),
downgrade to version 2.17.1. Since version 2.17.2 contains mostly fixes to the Log4j 1 Bridge, this might unfortunately cause some NoClassDefFoundErrors,
you can also call Configurator.reconfigure() in your code. This should relaunch the automatic configuration procedure.


Thank you Piotr, I will look at the workaround. If I understood correctly, the last option from the workaround I need to use in combination with ConfigurationListener? On Configuration change - reconfigure it back to the original.

If you know when the third-party library initializes logging, you can run Configurator.reconfigure() just after it. ConfigurationListener is not a good place to trigger a reconfiguration.
